# SOCK_SEQPACKET is buffering ~42k of data, how to limit it to less?

Tags: linux, sockets

An example client(http://pastebin.com/hAbpFPia) and server(http://pastebin.com/9pL27hkK) using SOCK_SEQPACKET, indicate that the client can queue up ~42k of data.

Using setsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF,...) to set the size on the client size does limit the buffered data significantly. Is there some way I can enforce/set this limit from the server side? I tried setting SO_RCVBUF on the accept()ed socket and the socket before calling accept() but neither works for me.

Using AF_UNIX.

Comment: What AF_ are you using? Is it af_unix for a local unix socket or some other af that is going over the network wire?

Comment: Its AF_UNIX, editing the post.

Comment: In case you did not notify it, I modified my answer: SO_RCVBUF does not have an effect on unix domain sockets.

Comment: How do you know? Are you familiar with the internals of kernel networking? Test application??

Comment: No, I am not. I got my information from http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html. I get the same information with `man unix` on Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: I had no idea there was a page call 'unix'. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server cannot enforce a SO_SNDBUF size on the client.

SO_SNDBUF limits the buffer that the sender's OS uses. The sending application can send up to SO_SNDBUF bytes, even if the underlying network cannot send the data right now, until a send would block. The OS takes care to send this data when the network stack is able to accept a new send.

SO_RCVBUF if the buffer that the receiver's OS uses. The network stack is receiving (and acknowledging to the sender) up to SO_RCVBUF bytes, even if the application does not call recv to retrieve the data. For unix domain sockets SO_RCVBUF does not have any effect, but SO_SNDBUF has.

As you can see both buffers sum up. And they are working on different ends of the network connection. They do not affect each other and the receiver cannot enforce a SO_SNDBUF on the sender's side - as the sender cannot enforce a SO_RCVBUF on the receiver's side.

Comment: Hmm. I appreciate the info, this is kind of what I thought in terms of how it was working internally. So to backtrack, I was using SOCK_SEQPACKET to get framing of data. I'd like the buffering to be as small as I want. Is there some alternate mechanism I can use to accomplish the same thing? I could use SOCK_STREAM but then I'd need message framing for this particular use case...